# What is the best formula for combining two parameters with different priority?

Tags: scoring-algorithm

I have a pretty general question: I'm working on my thesis and I took an online test from some people. I want to assign score to each person based on

1. number of their correct answer (C) and
2. their average response time (T).
   My idea for scoring them is to divide number of correct answer by average response time (C/T). So more correct answers and less average response time, leads to higher score.

The problem is that I prefer to reduce impact of T on scores (C is more important) but I don't know What is the best formula.

Comment: When you divide the total number of correct answers by the total time used, then you get the average number of correct answers per time unit, i.e. a rate at which correct answers occurred. Can you use this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One method is to normalise your two parameters so they give answers between 0 and 1 and then apply a weighting to each when combining them. Thus $C_N$ and $T_N$ are the normalised response time and with $C_{max}$ the maximum possible score and $T_{min}$ the minimum possible response time.

Therefore $C_N=C/C_{max}$ and $T_N=T_{min}/T$

You can now attach the weighting e.g. $0.75*C_N+0.25*T_N$ . If you use percentage weightings that add up to 1 (100%) then the output from the formula will always be a number between 0 and 1 which can then be scaled and rounded appropriately.